# How to change the separator colour of one table view cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2

How can I change the `separatorColor` property for only one cell in a uitableview. If I do `self.tableView.separatorColor = ...` it changes all the separator colours. Any idea how I can only change one cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible using only iOS APIs. The recommended way to do this is to set the separatorColor to `UIColor.clearColor` and then implement your own using something like this in the cell's setData function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
    if(condition for unique color) {
         var bottomBorder = CALayer()
         bottomBorder.backgroundColor = (special color)
         bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height - 1, cell.frame.size.width, 1)
         cell.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
    }
    else {
         var bottomBorder = CALayer()
         bottomBorder.backgroundColor = (unspecial color)
         bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height - 1, cell.frame.size.width, 1)
         cell.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Of course you can set the color to change based on the data of that cell.

Comment: ok....im not familiar with setData. Never heard of it. Can u give me some more detail or link me somewhere where i can find out more please?

Comment: when I say `setData`, I am referring to whatever function you call to customize the cell. You must have one, otherwise each cell will look the same. It is probably not literally called `setData`

Comment: like cellForRowAtIndex?

Comment: Usually you'll call your `setData` function in cellForRowAtIndex`. If not, you can use the above code directly in cellForRowAtIndex as long as you make sure the color changes when it needs to.

Comment: ah ok...ill give it a shot

Comment: I've revised my answer to work using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` directly

Comment: this code doesn't work. It says CALayer.layer is unavailable.

Comment: Have you imported QuartzCore?

Comment: See revision. Replace it with `CALayer()`

Comment: it's also giving me issues with 1.0f. if i take out the f it should still be fine right?

Comment: Ah yes. Typo on my end.

Comment: Try subtracting 1 from the height in the frames.

Comment: sorry one more thing. Now how would I add this layer to the top of the section?

Answer (score 0):

To simpler, you can add a uilabel in bottom of uitableviewcell, and set constraint for it. It is in storyboard, so it is easier
This frame of uilabel is (0,cell.frame.size.heigh - 1, cell.frame.size.width, 1)